# VerifyError in run app on device

Tags: android

My device Firmware version is 1.6 and whenever I run my application on Device I got an error :

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(834): java.lang.VerifyError:
dalvikvm(834): VFY: unable to resolve static field 966 (CONTENT_URI) in Landroid/provider/ContactsContract$CommonDataKinds$Phone;

I think I am getting this error because of "android.provider.ContactsContract" class to build my application? because it's API level is 5 .

So can any body help me to resolve the issue and how can I run a single build on 1.5 and 1.6 and 2.0 - above sdk ?

ThanksInAdvance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [reflection](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Pick/) or [conditional class loading](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/) to support multiple API levels like this.

Comment: The "backward compatibility" article from the Android developer blog has been collected with several others in the developer docs.  See http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html .